# Checking if Auth0 idToken has expired

Tags: ios, swift, auth0

I have a Swift App, which implements the web login for Auth0. On successful login, i receive an **access token** and and **idToken**, which i both store locally in my Keychain. Upon next login, i first check, if the access token (stored in keychain) is still valid by

```
Auth0
     .authentication()
     .userInfo(withAccessToken: accessToken)
     .start { result in
         switch result {
         case .success(result: let profile):

             print("access token still valid")
```

On success does not have to login again. The issue i'm having however, is, that my idToken might be expired already, even though my access token is still valid, which leads to errors when i request my (GraphQL) backend with this idToken. So how do i solve this? Is there a way to check, if my idToken has expired in Swift? Because if there is no way to check, i would have to ask for login, even with potentially not expired tokens. That wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An `idToken` is a JSON Web Token (JWT), so the metadata is readable. To see what this looks like, paste your token into jwt.io and see what the format is.

For example, take this JWT:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiZXhwIjoiMTUwNDc1MzQ0NSIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlfQ.ggeW2vGcdWKNWmICRfTZ8qcBOQlu38DzaO8t_6aNuHQ
```

It is broken into 3 parts: the header, the payload, and the signature. The expiration is in the payload section.

We just need to base64 decode this.

```
let jwt = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvbiBTbm93IiwiZXhwIjoiMTUwNDc1MzQ0NSIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlfQ.aCiqyVAAmHizPshrcdy8jwgHvBg4Diz2YY2e1INjoPg"

// get the payload part of it
var payload64 = jwt.components(separatedBy: ".")[1]

// need to pad the string with = to make it divisible by 4,
// otherwise Data won't be able to decode it
while payload64.count % 4 != 0 {
    payload64 += "="
}

print("base64 encoded payload: \(payload64)")
let payloadData = Data(base64Encoded: payload64,
                       options:.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
let payload = String(data: payloadData, encoding: .utf8)!
print(payload)
```

This prints out:

```
{"sub":"1234567890","name":"Jon Snow","exp":"1504753445","admin":true}
```

The `exp` is your expiration date. You can pass this off to a JSON serializer to get the date:

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: payloadData, options: []) as! [String:Any]
let exp = json["exp"] as! Int
let expDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(exp))
let isValid = expDate.compare(Date()) == .orderedDescending
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped!

Comment: @Ben Scheirman: Did this way affected if a user changes their OS time in Settings?

Comment: @Bad_Developer client side checks are really only to know if you should refresh or not. The server will still validate this on their end, and reject the token with a 401 response. So you need to handle both cases. In my apps, when the token is expired (or about to expire) I will proactively refresh the token first to avoid getting a 401.